# filling numpy array with random element from another array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm not sure if this is possible but here goes.  Suppose I have an array:

```
array1 = [0,.1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6,.7,.8,.9,1]
```

and now I would like to create a numpy 1D array consisting of 5 elements that are randomly drawn from array1 AND with the condition that the sum is equal to 1. Example is something like, a numpy array that looks like `[.2,.2,.2,.1,.1]`.

- currently I use the random module, and choice function that looks like this:
  `range1=  np.array([choice(array1),choice(array1),choice(array1),choice(array1),choice(array1)])`
  then checking range1 to see if it meets the criteria; I'm wondering if there is faster way , something similar to 
  `randomArray = np.random.random()` instead.
- Would be even better if I can store this array in some library so that if I try to generate 100 of such array, that there is no repeat but this is not necessary.

Comment: Your constraint that the values add to 1 greatly limits the valid choices. Are duplicates picks allowed? If not, the only valid choice is `[0, .1, .2, .3, .4]`, which should add up close to `1` (floating point rounding may cause problems if you're not careful). If duplicates are allowed, then there's more than one option and the problem isn't trivial.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.random.choice`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html#numpy.random.choice) if you use numpy 1.7.0+:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> array1 = np.array([0,.1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6,.7,.8,.9,1])
>>> np.random.choice(array1, 5)
array([ 0. ,  0. ,  0.3,  1. ,  0.3])
>>> np.random.choice(array1, 5, replace=False)
array([ 0.6,  0.8,  0.1,  0. ,  0.4])
```

---

To get 5 elements that the sum is equal to 1,

- generate 4 random numbers.
- substract the sum of 4 numbers from 1 -> x
- if x included in array1, use that as final number; or repeat

---

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> def solve(arr, total, n):
...     while True:
...         xs = np.random.choice(arr, n-1)
...         remain = total - xs.sum()
...         if remain in arr:
...             return np.append(xs, remain)
... 
>>> array1 = np.array([0,.1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6,.7,.8,.9,1])
>>> print solve(array1, 1, 5)
[ 0.1  0.3  0.4  0.2  0. ]
```

---

Another version (assume given array is sorted):

```
EPS = 0.0000001
def solve(arr, total, n):
    while True:
        xs = np.random.choice(arr, n-1)
        t = xs.sum()
        i = arr.searchsorted(total - t)
        if abs(t + arr[i] - total) < EPS:
            return np.append(xs, arr[i])
```

Comment: This solution may have issues due to floating point rounding. It will never produce `[0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0, 0.4]` (in that order), because when you calculate `1-(0.2+0.2+0.2)` you get `0.3999999999999999` rather than `0.4`. (This is why my solution uses integers :-). I'm also not sure that this algorithm generates a uniform distribution of solutions. That said, I'm actually not sure how to determine the distribution it produces, so it might do better than I think.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do something similar a while ago.

```
def getRandomList(n, source):
    '''
    Returns a list of n elements randomly selected from source.
    Selection is done without replacement.

    '''

    list = source
    indices = range(len(source))
    randIndices = []
    for i in range(n):
        randIndex = indices.pop(np.random.randint(0, high=len(indices)))
        randIndices += [randIndex]

    return [source[index] for index in randIndices]


data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
randomData = getRandomList(4, data)
print randomData
```

Comment: If you're using numpy already, why not just do `numpy.random.choice(source, n, False)`?

Comment: @Blckknght I hadn't heard of this function before but I think you're right - it's much easier that way.

Comment: `high` for [`numpy.random.randint`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html#numpy.random.randint) is exclusive. You should pass `len(indices)` instead.

Comment: I'm also using something like this that seem to work as well range1 =  1.0* (np.random.random_integers(1,10, size=(1,5))) / 10

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about the order of the values in the output sequences, the number of 5-value combinations of values from your list that add up to 1 is pretty small. In the specific case you proposed though, it's a bit complicated to calculate, since floating point values have rounding issues. You can more easily solve the issue if you use a set of integers (e.g. `range(11)`)and find combinations that add up to 10. Then if you need the fractional values, just divide the values in the results by 10.

Anyway, here's a generator that yields all the possible sets that add up to a given value:

```
def picks(values, n, target):
    if n == 1:
        if target in values:
            yield (target,)
        return
    for i, v in enumerate(values):
        if v <= target:
            for r in picks(values[i:], n-1, target-v):
                yield (v,)+r
```

Here's the results for the numbers zero through ten:

```
>>> for r in picks(range(11), 5, 10):
    print(r)

(0, 0, 0, 0, 10)
(0, 0, 0, 1, 9)
(0, 0, 0, 2, 8)
(0, 0, 0, 3, 7)
(0, 0, 0, 4, 6)
(0, 0, 0, 5, 5)
(0, 0, 1, 1, 8)
(0, 0, 1, 2, 7)
(0, 0, 1, 3, 6)
(0, 0, 1, 4, 5)
(0, 0, 2, 2, 6)
(0, 0, 2, 3, 5)
(0, 0, 2, 4, 4)
(0, 0, 3, 3, 4)
(0, 1, 1, 1, 7)
(0, 1, 1, 2, 6)
(0, 1, 1, 3, 5)
(0, 1, 1, 4, 4)
(0, 1, 2, 2, 5)
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
(0, 1, 3, 3, 3)
(0, 2, 2, 2, 4)
(0, 2, 2, 3, 3)
(1, 1, 1, 1, 6)
(1, 1, 1, 2, 5)
(1, 1, 1, 3, 4)
(1, 1, 2, 2, 4)
(1, 1, 2, 3, 3)
(1, 2, 2, 2, 3)
(2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
```

You can select one of them at random (with `random.choice`), or if you plan on using many of them and you don't want to repeat yourself, you can use `random.shuffle`, then iterate.

```
results = list(picks(range(11), 5, 10))
random.shuffle(results)

for r in results:
    # do whatever you want with r
```

Comment: HI Blckknght: this works very well - I don't understand how it works but will study it to learn more.  thank you much.

Comment: The algorithm is similar to one for making change for a certain value given a set of coin denominations. However, instead of trying to make change with the fewest coins, in this case I'm trying to pick exactly `n` items that add up to `target`. The first `if` is the base case, where there's just one value left to pick. If the `target` value is available in the list, we pick it! The loop is the recursive case, where you pick one value, then recurse to find a smaller set that add up to the remaining part of the value.

Comment: Hi Blckknght, what if order matters? Say if I also want the sequences (0, 0, 0, 1, 9) as well as (9,1,0,0,0)? thanks.

Comment: @AlexLee: It's complicated. Do you want each of the unique permutations of the result sequences to be equally likely? If so, a solution like `(2,2,2,2,2)` that has only a single unique permutation is going to be much rarer than the five unique permutations of `(0,0,0,0,10)` or the 20 unique permutations of `(0,0,0,1,9)`. My generator can do this if you remove the slice from the recursive step: `for r in picks(values, n-1, target-v):` (you can get rid of the `enumerate` call too, if you want). This produces about 33 times as many results though (and may take much more time)!

Comment: Thanks Blckknght - you are incredible - people like u makes the internet great.  Laters.